# My joystick is not working in FIFA 11 when playing

Tags: controllers, fifa-11

My [vinyson joystick](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=vinyson%20joystick&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1024&bih=550) not working when I am trying to play the match, but it works outside of the game when I am selecting menu etc.

I think I am doing something wrong. I am very new to this joystick stuff.

Comment: Have you selected joystick as the in-game control?  A lot of games will disable it if keyboard is selected in the options, and vice-versa.

Comment: no, i am selecting the joystick in the game but other button of joystick working but the moving control is not working.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked. With vinyson joystick you have to active the analog mode by pressing to analog button for joystick to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only some controllers are compatible with FIFA 11. For example, I tried to play FIFA 11 on the PC with a PS2 controller, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. Your joystick is not supported, you can only use it in the menu. You need to buy a Logitech or some other compatible with fifa 11.

Comment: Actually it did worked. I had to active the analog key before using the joystick. :)

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept that one. Nobody will mind! :)

Answer (score -2):

or you can go to ea sports folder fifa11 game fifa setup and fifa config and go to controller and just put your keys it works !